# Upgrade Job Title to reflect responsiblites for a Salary Bump request

Tags: raise, title

I am at my current position for 7 years.

I was initially hired for pricing related data analysis, most of which was very manual/technical work. A typical tasks would involve a profit report from the company, a transaction list from a specific website and a chart of general rates where I would need to compare all info at hand and decide the best way forward.

With time I realized that a large percent of the work could and should be automated, I slowly entered the world of VBA (Most of the reports we deal with are excel based). I took an online course, I read a book...

At this point I have 10+ macros or "mini programs" in use by my teammates, greatly increasing productivity. About half of which was put together whenever there was a lull in the work.

I got verbal acknowledgements and somewhat decent raises over the years. Then a year ago upper management decided to officially designate majority of my time to writing these macros, with a promised not very significant "Bonus" at the end of the year.

My current title is "Senior Pricing Analyst"
It falls short in description and salary.
I would like to approach my seniors saying I feel"Xyz" would be a more all encompassing title and my current contributions is worth a ($) salary increase.

Note I am still doing pricing analysis in order to stay current with trends and rates (and to lend a hand when the rest of the team is overwhelmed...)
Also, I am not really a developer or programmer, but I technically write "mini programs"

Any ideas? suggestions? tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: Very nice advice there but I really need ideas for a title upgrade. I know that will talk the most to my boss. (I know titles don't always hold much water but in my case this can be the way to open the door)

Answer (score 1):

It depends a LOT on the nature of how your company interprets and uses titles.  I've been in companies that titles DO influence pay levels.  Been in others where the two seem almost entirely divorced from the other.

Without knowing more about your company culture, it's hard to say if a title change will help you or not.

However, since you can prove you are providing additional benefits to the companies bottum line via your new work, I'd emphasize this, more than anything else, as reasons for a new raise.  I'd just skip a new title, unless your company is one that has strict pay bands per position, and your pay level would exceed your current pay band. I've seen more than once someone given a new title in lieu of a raise.  Think of which you're really after, and just persue that.

Comment: Yeah my company is stupidly strict with pay bands and I probably maxed out mine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all titles aren't comparable between companies.

> My current title is "Senior Pricing Analyst" It falls short in
> description and salary. I would like to approach my seniors saying I
> feel"Xyz" would be a more all encompassing title and my current
> contributions is worth a ($) salary increase.

You will need to know what is the salary band for your current job title, there is no use asking for a raise in pay if the current title won't allow it.

You will need to know what would be the next title, and what is that title's pay range. If that meets you needs: a healthy increase but still in the lower half of the pay range for the new title, you will need to see what you need to do to get that promotion. It could require something you don't have.

Then you have to look at other titles you think you could qualify for. You said you aren't a programmer, but there may be enough titles that require some programming that you can qualify in one of those other titles. If these have higher pay bands then advocate for a change in title.

The list of potential titles is specific to your company. The requirements for those titles is specific to your company.

Now if your company is so small that they don't have those things mapped out, then you will need to talk with your manager to see what can be done to receive the pay you deserve.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the naming that your employer uses. But one grade above "Senior Foo" could be "Principal Foo".

But I would expect to see a considerable increase in responsibility at that level, not simply a bit more experience.

Comment: I already have that increase in responsibility... it just came without an official promotion